# Logging and Scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, data-mining

I tried to Log in into website [tanfonline.com](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/showLogin?uri=%2Fjournals%2Ftadp20) . In order to scrape data with selenium library in python, I need to log in. However, the server Identified me as a robot so I tried to use undetected_chromedriver library. I wasn't able to move in into the next screen of registration when I enter my password and email.

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

#password = 'bri92#Ga'
#email = 'ido.koubi@live.biu.ac.il'
chrome = Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/action/showLogin?uri=%2F")
time.sleep(120)
chrome.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"a").find_element(By.XPATH,'//* 
[@id="frmLogin"]/div[2]/ul/li/a').click()
login = chrome.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input").find_element(By.XPATH,'//* 
[@id="shibboleth_search"]/div/input').click()
select = chrome.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input").find_element(By.XPATH,'//* 
[@id="shibboleth_search"]/div/input').send_keys("Bar-Ilan University")
action = ActionChains(chrome)
action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


chrome.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17452750500283590")
```

Comment: _I wasn't able to move in into the next screen_ What exactly do you mean "wasn't able"?  Why, exactly?  Did you get an error?  Did the browser not proceed to the correct url?  Please explain **in detail**.

Comment: I didn't get an error message ,but the server didn't proceed into the next screen, where I need to fill my password.

Comment: What does the browser do after sending "Bar-Ilan University"?  Try commenting out the last `chrome.get()` line to see what the browser shows.

Comment: after sending "Bar-Ilan University" it freezes using the code select = chrome.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"input").find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="shibboleth_search"]/div/input').send_keys("Bar-Ilan University")
it freezes, and if I enter click() method together with find_element() , it refer me to a screen with captcha and then returns an error.

Comment: You probably need to add a short delay after pressing the "login" button.  That's what a human would do.